# How to read multiple worksheets from a single .csv file?

Tags: php

I want to read multiple worksheets in a single `.csv` file using PHP. I have done it for one worksheet:

```
$file_handle = fopen("widgets.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";
}

fclose($file_handle);
```

But how can I read multiple worksheets from the same `.csv` file?

Comment: CSV files don't have multiple worksheets. It must be an xsl file or similar. Look for libraries that can interpret the actual file type.

Comment: Please do not undo my edits after improving your grammar.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as multiple sheets in `.csv` files.

This is something unique to `.xls`/`.xlsx` files.

`.csv` files contain only a single worksheet<sup>*</sup>.

<sup><sup>*</sup> actually they don't contain *any* worksheets, since there is no concept of worksheets</sup>

Comment: Also CSV doesn't include colors, or any formatting, as well as any dynamic functions - I can see that being his next question :)